# How to unhighlight 1st special caracter if any

Tags: regex

`(?:[^.]|^)((?:\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|0?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|0?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b(?=[^.:/]|$))`

this highlights correct IPv4 address, but if at front there are any special characters, it also highlights the same.

`11.22.44.33` - OK

`@11.22.44.33` - also highlights 1st character - @, which I don't want. I just want to highlight rest of the part

Answer (score 0):

The `@` will match your REGEX, but it won't be captured in your capturing group.

I'm not sure what software you're using it with, but group 1 will contain just the IP address, and not the `@`.

If you simply don't want it to match at all for whatever reason, remove the first part of your REGEX:

`(?:[^.]|^)`

As this matches anything that isn't a literal `.` or the beginning of a line/string. I'm not sure you actually need this part anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my requirement is to highlight correct iPv4 address. instead of @ or any other special character, if you add "Space" it also highlights the same, which I don't want

Comment: Highlight in what though? You are capturing the exact iPv4 address in group 1, can you not use this data? I don't fully understand your requirement, do you mean you only want to match if there is absolutely nothing else in the same string?